# Different Config Files in GitHub Repo Branch

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

So I have a GitHub repo with a master branch and a staging branch, they both have separate config files for deploying to different places.  I was hoping that when I perform a pull request on the staging branch back to master, that I could some how exclude the 2 config files that I want to remain different in both branches.

How can I achieve this in the easiest way?  A permanent solution would be great, but from what I've read so far it would involve doing a "stash" and a "pop"?  Or maybe just performing an "undo" / "revert" after the 2 config files are overwritten?

This isn't ideal for me as it will cause Travis-CI to kick off 2 separate compilation / deployment processes.

Nick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `ours` strategy. Create a file named `.gitattributes` in your both branches and add the following content in it:

```
path/to/your/config.json merge=ours
```

Then commit your the `.gitattributes` files:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Added gitattributes'
```

Comment: So just so I understand this correctly, that forces each branch to maintain its own version of that file?  And lastly, stupid noob question before I get it wrong, if the file is in the root of my repo, would the path just be

"config.json merge=ours"

Comment: @Nick *that forces each branch to maintain its own version of that file?*–exactly! This even works when you want to merge something, but don't want to override your files, for some reason: `git merge some-branch -s ours`. And yes, if your file is in the root, just put `config.json merge=ours`.

Comment: @Nick Also, don't forget to mark the answer if it helps you (I see you have lot of questions without marked questions)... `:-)`

Comment: First try hasn't worked as expected and the staging branch overwrote my master branch config when I accepted the pull request, will try again in a second.  I must have done something wrong.

Comment: It worked the second time, phew! Thanks a million for your time.

Comment: @Nick Great! You're welcome! Please mark the answer then, by clicking the **`✔`** button (left side of my answer).

Comment: Sorry I thought I had, I pressed the up vote button instead, all done now, thanks.

Comment: Does this mean that neither branch will ever perform a fast-forward merge with the other, now? If you merge staging into master, then master into staging, they would still be different because of the difference in the coming files?

Comment: *Does this mean that neither branch will ever perform a fast-forward merge with the other, now?*–Hmm, actually yes. I don't see any better solution here. Actually when you edit config files you should commit them without a merge.

Comment: I know this comment comes considerably late, but we did get merge issues in the end. So I worked around it by putting all of my config data into a single file.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I have a rather long list of config files that I can't just combine into one.  I've added each in a separate line in the format `relative/path/config merge=ours`.  After committing the changes, the merge does overwrite.  Is there a specific format the `.gitattributes` needs to be in for multiple files?